# Creating a User model for Facebook login

Tags: facebook-login

I'm trying to User model and add in some necessary fields that Omniauth uses for user authentication.

Run the following command from terminal:

rails g model User provider uid name oauth_token oauth_expires_at:datetime

but I'm getting an error message saying that 
 invoke active_record

The name 'User' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails.Please chose an alternative and run this generator again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you already have the `app/models/user.rb` file in your project and the rails generator complains about that

Comment: Awww okay!!Let me use a different word then to generate the new model.Yay,It worked!!!Thanks @Nikolay:D!!You're a life saver!!